# Database not getting populated

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form which contains two radio buttons.

Like :

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" name="make_trans" action="<?php echo root; ?>airpay.html" method="post" onsubmit = "return validate();">
 <input type="hidden" id="buyerEmail" name="buyerEmail" value="<?php echo $order['email']; ?>" onkeypress = "changecolor(this.id,'buyerEmailspan')" maxlength = "50"> 
 <input type="hidden" id="buyerPhone" name="buyerPhone" value="<?php echo $order['contact_no']; ?>" onkeypress = "changecolor(this.id,'buyerPhonespan')" maxlength = "15">
 <input type="hidden" id="buyerFirstName" name="buyerFirstName" value="<?php echo $order['first_name']; ?>" onkeypress = "changecolor(this.id,'buyerFirstNamespan')" maxlength = "50">
 <input type="hidden" id="buyerLastName" name="buyerLastName" value="<?php echo $order['last_name']; ?>" onkeypress = "changecolor(this.id,'buyerLastNamespan')" maxlength = "50">
 <input type="hidden" id="buyerAddress" name="buyerAddress" maxlength = "255" value="<?php echo $order['address']; ?>" onkeypress = "changecolor(this.id,'buyerAddressspan')">
 <input type="hidden" id="buyerCity" name="buyerCity" maxlength = "50" value="<?php echo $order['city']; ?>" onkeypress = "changecolor(this.id,'buyerCityspan')">
 <input type="hidden" id="buyerState" name="buyerState" maxlength = "50" value="<?php echo $order['state']; ?>" onkeypress = "changecolor(this.id,'buyerStatespan')">
 <input type="hidden" id="buyerCountry" name="buyerCountry" maxlength = "50" value="<?php echo $order['country']; ?>" onkeypress = "changecolor(this.id,'buyerCountryspan')">
 <input type="hidden" id="buyerPinCode" name="buyerPinCode" maxlength = "8" value="<?php echo $order['pin']; ?>" onkeypress = "changecolor(this.id,'buyerPinCodespan')" >
 <input type="hidden" id="orderid" name="orderid" value="<?php echo $order['order_no']; ?>" onkeypress = "changecolor(this.id,'orderidspan')">
 <input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="<?php echo number_format($order['totalAmt'],2,'.',''); ?>" onkeypress = "changecolor(this.id,'amountspan')">
 
 <center>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="label-checkbox">
    <input type="radio" name = "delivery_options" id = "cod" value = "cod">
    Cash On Delivery
   </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <label class="label-checkbox">
    <input type="radio" name = "delivery_options" id = "pay_now" value = "pay_now">
    Pay Now
   </label>
   <?php
    if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST ') && (isset($_POST['submit'])))
     {
      if ($_POST['delivery_options'] == "cod")
       {
        $payment_mode = "COD";
       }
      else ($_POST['delivery_options'] == "pay_now")
       {
        header('Location: http://localhost/ovenfresh/airpay.html');
       }
     }
    ?>
  </div>
 </center>
 <center>
        <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px;">Your Order No is # <?php echo $order['order_no']; ?> and Billing Amount is <?php echo number_format($order['totalAmt'],2); ?></p>    
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </div>
 </center>
</form>
```

Now on selecting Cash On Delivery one Insert query has to be performed and on selecting Pay Now redirect to another page.

I tried this. All other fields are getting filled except *payment_mode*

Database Query :

```
$order = array('customer_id'    =>  $customer_id,
                   'subtotal'   =>  $_POST['subtotal'],
                   'totalAmt'   =>  $_POST['totalAmt'],
                   'dileveryAmt'    =>  $_POST['dileveryAmt'],
                   'date'   =>  date('Y-m-d'),
                  'midnightdelivery'    =>  $_POST['midnightdelivery'],
                  'delivery_date'   =>  $_POST['delivery_date'],
                  'message_on_cake' =>  $_POST['message_on_cake'],
                  'special_instruction' =>  $_POST['special_instruction'],
                  'payment_mode'    =>  $_POST['payment_mode']
                  );
    $order_id = $this->db->insert('orders',$order);
```

---

```
function insert($table=null,$array_of_values=array()) {
    if ($table===null || empty($array_of_values) || !is_array($array_of_values)) return false;
    $fields=array(); $values=array();
    foreach ($array_of_values as $id => $value) {
        $fields[]=$id;
        if (is_array($value) && !empty($value[0])) $values[]=$value[0];
        else $values[]="'".mysql_real_escape_string($value,$this->con)."'";
    }
    $s = "INSERT INTO $table (".implode(',',$fields).') VALUES ('.implode(',',$values).')';
    if (mysql_query($s,$this->con)) return mysql_insert_id($this->con);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you have not closed the php tag correctly in your form action. and whats that **root** in action

Comment: That was a typo error. root contains root directory. ('http://localhost/ovenfresh/')

Answer (score 2):

You are checking with the wrong phrase, remove the space

```
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST ')&& (isset($_POST['submit'])))
```

in to

```
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') && (isset($_POST['submit'])))
```

There are more errors, like the double `class` in your button tag. Check your code carefully.

Answer (score 2):

I can see 2 reasons why your code may not work correctly. The first is the comparison you have here:

> if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST ') && (isset($_POST['submit'])))

Should change to:

> if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') && (isset($_POST['submit'])))

All I did was remove the space in the string literal to change it from 'POST ' to 'POST' (the trailing space means the two are not equal). Also, I don't think the key 'submit' in $_POST is set either since you haven't set a name for your submit button. So you should also change:

> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

to

> <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

The change I made was adding the attribute "name" with the value "submit".

Secondly, in your second snippet of code the following line may be the offender:

> 'payment_mode'    =>  $_POST['payment_mode']

There is no such key ('payment_mode') defined in $_POST (judging only from the code you have supplied). The payment mode is instead stored at the key 'delivery_options' and later on in the variable $payment_mode.

So the problem may be resolved by changing the following line:

> 'payment_mode'    =>  $_POST['payment_mode']

to

> 'payment_mode'    =>  $_POST['delivery_options']

or

> 'payment_mode'    =>  $payment_mode

Answer (score 1):

Hm, you did not post the full code so it will be hard, but as the way i see, the reason is not saving, because `$_POST['payment_mode']` is not defined anywhere, but you store it in a variable.

So change this line

```
 'payment_mode'    =>  $_POST['payment_mode']
```

To this

```
'payment_mode'    =>  $payment_mode
```

Comment: Tried that too. Codes are in different files so may not be able to post full code(I am not sure but its some kind of framework)

Comment: it will be a hard nut this way

Answer (score 0):

Make two changes

1.`if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST ') && (isset($_POST['submit'])))`

change to

`if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') && (isset($_POST['submit'])))`

2. `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>`

change to

`<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>`